# python pandas dataframe mutate all elements as (element / max element in row)

Tags: python, pandas

df=

```
x1, x2, x3, x4, x5...x90, 'ignore'
37.4, 35.6, 43.5, 33.3, 42.4...42.5, 'ignoe'
32.2, 37.2, 43.4, 34.3, 82.4...22.1, 44
33.5, 45.5, 25.9, 23.8, 24.2...52.2, True
35.4, 30.6, 33.3, 33.3, 42.5...82.5, 'ignre'
```

I want to mutate all of the elements so they will all be between 0-1, by dividing each element by the max element in the row, ignoring the last column (there will not be any negative numbers or 0)

The problem I am having is it needs to be performant on millions of rows but iterating over rows in pandas is very slow

I believe this works but it is very slow

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    rowMax = max(row.drop(columns='ignore'))
    for i in range(1, 91):
        df.loc[index, 'x' + str(i)] = df.loc[index, 'x' + str(i)] / rowMax
```

output:

```
x1, x2, x3, x4, x5...x90, 'ignore'
0.86, 0.82, 1.00, 0.77, 0.97...0.98, 'ignoe'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.update(df.iloc[:,0:90].div(df.max(axis=1), axis=0))
```

First, you should grab the part of the dataframe you want to do the divide on: `df.iloc[:,0:90]` which means for every row pick the columns from 0 to 89.

Then, you grab the max of each row with: `df.max(axis=1)`. Because your ignore column does not have all values as numerical, it would be ignored by `max` function so no worries about that.

Then, you do a divide with `axis=0` meaning that divide on each row.

And, as the last step, you update the dataframe.

Comment: Could you please explain? Why is your code fast and my code slow?

Comment: @GFG iterating over a dataframe with for loops is a very very time-taking operation. The intention of the creation of libraries like pandas is also to address those performance issues. So if you use library codes which are optimized (and in some cases parallel, ...) would help a lot.

Comment: so are you essentially creating an intermediate dataframe with the max value from each row then dividing that with the original frame

Comment: Yeah, `df.max(axis=1)` gives you the max value of each row and then we divide the part of dataframe you are interested in (`df.iloc[:,0:90]`) with those max values.

Comment: it seems to me that the number of overall computations we are doing should be the same then. i don't understand why mine is slow and yours is fast beyond "pandas dataframes are designed to be more efficient with these types of operations."

Answer (score 1):

Try Using apply function [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

Remove any str or object column and store it some another variable and concatenate it after the operation
I created the the data frame of size

```
df.shape
Out[38]: (1000000, 91)

col = pd.DataFrame(df['col_str']) # Storing Categorical Col
df = df.drop('col_str', axis=1) # Dropping the col

start = datetime.now()    
tmp = df.apply(lambda x : x/max(x), axis=1, raw=True)
print(datetime.now()-start)
0:00:16.693436
```

It took around 16secs